# Why Jquery datepicker popup doesn't appear next to the textbox to which it's associated in IE?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have several textboxes that I use for calendar purpose.

```
function SetUpDatePicker() {
   var $allDatepickers = $('.datepicker');
    $.each($allDatepickers, function () {
       $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

FF and Chrome work fine, i.e. the calendar appear under the textbox that was clicked.

But for the IE, no matter where the textbox is located, the calendar always appear next to the first textbox.

Any idea why?

Comment: @gdoron: textbox that is used for the datepicker is inside a gridrow. The gridview itself is inside a usercontrol. Finally, there are 5 usercontrols in that same page. I don't know how to put that in the fiddle. I'll try.

Comment: @gdoron: http://jsfiddle.net/Richard77/7S9RC/

Comment: @Richard77: your JS is needlessly complex: http://jsfiddle.net/7S9RC/1/

Comment: You need to copy enough markup to reproduce the problem. Also define "IE" - do you experience the issue with all IEs from 6 to 10 or which one specifically?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but why not simplify your initialization to `$('.datepicker').datepicker()`?

Comment: @jrummell: because I have more logic to add depending on some conditions.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I'm using IE9

Comment: This seems to work for me in IE9 assuming you add in jQuery UI and call that function. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cu3Ej/)